# TLS fails in server box but works fine locally

Tags: c#, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have a website calling a web API via https, everything in C#.net, and it was working just fine until, the providers of the API changed the certificate to remove SSL and I began to get:

```
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

After a fix in which I've added:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

To allow only tls ciphers, everything worked fine locally with the same URL I call on the live environment, but on the live server I still get:

```
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

I made sure the code was update, the the app pool recycled and the Tls protocols were Enable on the register keys.

Anyone has any suggestions? This a API is public third-party one

OPENSSL call to retrieve the certificate:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ws.purple-parking.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=GB/2.5.4.15=Private Organization/serialNumber=
02341479/C=GB/ST=MIDDLESEX/L=Southall/O=Purple Parking Limited/CN=www.purpleparking.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=GB/2.5.4.15=Private Organization/serialNumber=
02341479/C=GB/ST=MIDDLESEX/L=Southall/O=Purple Parking Limited/CN=www.purpleparking.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=GB/2.5.4.15=Private Organization/serialNumber=02341479/C=GB/ST=MIDDLESEX/L=Southall/O=Purple Parking Limited/CN=www.purpleparking.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=GB/2.5.4.15=Private Organization/serialNumber=023
41479/C=GB/ST=MIDDLESEX/L=Southall/O=Purple Parking Limited/CN=www.purpleparking.com
   i:/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./CN=thawte EV SSL CA - G3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.
- For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.
- For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=GB/2.5.4.15=Private Organization/serialNumber=
02341479/C=GB/ST=MIDDLESEX/L=Southall/O=Purple Parking Limited/CN=www.purpleparking.com
issuer=/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./CN=thawte EV SSL CA - G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5457 bytes and written 444 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: F286D708BDD3413C688722CCC5C89DA65217668DF16739C6495A8EF4216B3C76

    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 806065D476B184621B040B4E6E9E384BEDECF90551946E6B68AB6ABA530C5C208735676C249F06E56D081062017660E4
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1435830533
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
read:errno=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the server, Windows 2008 without the R2 service pack does not support TLS higher than v1.0